# Removing ajax load content

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap tabs.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

With

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
...
}
```

inside is simple ajax call

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax/records.php?type=" + url,
        beforeSend: function() {
            //$('#spinner_add').show()
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        },
        success: function(data) {
            generateView(data, url);
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
```

I'm detecting when tab is selected / clicked and that trigers ajax to load content. Contents is shown in table inside `<tbody>` and ajax loads rows for that table.

I have problem with refresh of data. Idealy, before new ajax call I would like to remove "old" rows, but since they are loaded dynamically I can't select them with normal selectors.

Advice?

Comment: When you populate the new information, wrap it in a `div` with an `id` and then use that id to find that div and do `$('div#id').html('');`

Comment: On creation of rows give them the same class name. On remove call remove on class name.